# java api send email to another person-Android Studio

Tags: java, android, email, android-studio, jakarta-mail

So i want to make a button send a mail like an application for registration. The user gives me his email in an edittext and an email will be sent from his mail to a specified email like "example@gmail.com".The app has no error but it doesn´t send any email.

I already have the JSSEProvider, GMailsender and the internet permission.

## JSSEProvider.java

```
import java.security.AccessController;

import java.security.Provider;



final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {



    JSSEProvider() {

        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");

        AccessController

                .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {

                    public Void run() {

                        put("SSLContext.TLS",

                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");

                        put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");

                        put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",

                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");

                        put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",

                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");

                        return null;

                    }

                });

    }

}
```

## GMailsender.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String user;

    private String password;

    private Session session;



    private Multipart _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    static {

        Security.addProvider(new com.example.android.elaborasoftware.JSSEProvider());

    }



    GMailSender(String user, String password) {

        this.user = user;

        this.password = password;



        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

        String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",

                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");



        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);

    }



    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);

    }



    synchronized void sendMail(String body,

                               String sender) throws Exception {

        try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(

                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));

            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));

            message.setSubject("Pedido de Registo");

            message.setDataHandler(handler);

            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            messageBodyPart.setText(body);

            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);



            // Put parts in message

            message.setContent(_multipart);

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (Exception ignored) {



        }

    }


    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {

        private byte[] data;

        private String type;





        ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {

            super();

            this.data = data;

            this.type = type;

        }



        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {

            super();

            this.data = data;

        }


        public String getContentType() {

            if (type == null)

                return "application/octet-stream";

            else

                return type;

        }



        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

        }



        public String getName() {

            return "ByteArrayDataSource";

        }



        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {

            throw new IOException("Not Supported");

        }

    }

}
```

my code looks like this:

## Register.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    final EditText etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final EditText etNumber = findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
    final EditText etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button btApplication = findViewById(R.id.btApplication);
    final String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    final String Name = etName.getText().toString();
    final String Number = etNumber.getText().toString();
    final String Password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    btApplication.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        GMailSender sender = new 
GMailSender(Email,Password);
                        sender.sendMail(Name + " send an application for 
registration by the android apk 'ElaboraSoftware' with the number: " + 
Number, Email);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

}
```

If someome could help i would be thankfull.

Comment: Be sure to use the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) and read and understand these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), many of which are included in the code below.  You might also find these [Gmail instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail) helpful.  And of course if you're going to send the message using the user's account, you're going to have to ask for the password, or use the much more complicated [OAuth2 authentication](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2).

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me....easiest way to send email.

Call `SendMail.class` like this

```
SendMail sm = new SendMail(context, "receiver@gmail.com", "Emergency Alert", email_message);
sm.execute();
```

**SendMail.class**

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;



//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context,String email,String subject,String message){
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Creating properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("sender@gmail.com", "example@2018");
                }
            });

    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding messageZZ
        mm.setText(message);

        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

also add `jar` file in `lib` folder

[mail.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.7/mail-1.4.7.jar)

Comment: @Dimitri Putin check my answer

Comment: Can´t test it right now to see if it works but i´ve implemented your code and i got no errors so thank you for the time you took to help me

Comment: shall i replace 
GMailSender sender = new 
GMailSender(Email,Password);
                        sender.sendMail(Name + " send an application for 
registration by the android apk 'ElaboraSoftware' with the number: " + 
Number, Email);

by SendMail sm = new SendMail(context, "receiver@gmail.com", "Emergency Alert", email_message);
sm.execute();